# Django - How can I save users ipaddress in admin log?

Tags: django

I am using django auth module.Now,when user logs in I want to record users ipaddress in the admin_log table.How can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a middleware, that will be called after `AuthenticationMiddleware` is called (it must be spcified after the latter in `settings.py`). In this middleware retrieve ip address from `HttpRequest.META` attribute (it would be probably `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`) and add this information to the `admin_log` table. But is `admin_log` exactly the place where you would like to store this information?

Comment: what other options do I have? Basically,admin should be able to see when users are logging in and the ipaddress they are using.

Comment: Why don't you create your own table for this information and show it in admin panel? `admin_log` is for operations made in admin panel, not for information about users logging in. I am not even sure, that you should store this kind of information in the database - maybe rather simply in log files? This can be done in a middleware too.

Comment: well the client wants to see in the admin section,so maybe I will go for custom table.

Comment: I have got it working.But,now I want to execute it only once when user logs in for the first time